# Are groups classed as static data within SignalR?

Tags: signalr

I am looking over SignalR as a possible way to manage messaging between clients on a web application. The scenario would be that one person would create a session/room, and a few other people would join it. Then everyone within that room would send messages to each other. A lot like a chat room however they would be sending variable update messages etc.

Now I keep seeing it said that static variables should not be used, which I completely agree with, but if it creates a new Hub (I am planning to use a hub due to the different types of messages) each request, how does it store the group each client is in?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you review the project's source code here. This project has been very good as you wanted.

https://github.com/davidfowl/JabbR

https://github.com/davidfowl/JabbR/blob/master/JabbR/Hubs/Chat.cs

Also you can look at here the title "Calling methods on specific clients or groups".

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Hubs

Comment: I have looked over their documentation, have not looked into the source code yet. I was hoping it would be a simple case of someone saying "Grouping is handled without needing static variables, allowing it to scale fine", but the JabbR link is helpful, thanks.